# 無限ループの発生するコードを書いてしまい、MonacaクラウドIDEが固まってしまう

Tags: monaca

初期ロード時に読み込まれるjavascriptに、`while(true) { }` と書き、誤って保存してしまい、それ以降、IDEでは自動的にアプリが実行されてしまうため、IDEが固まってしまい、動作しなくなりました。
どのようにすればこの状況から抜けられるでしょうか？

Answer (score 7):

[質問者のコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/22455/monaca%E3%81%8C%E7%84%A1%E9%99%90%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%81%A7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#comment21310_22458)より引用（一部整形しています）：

> ダッシュボードにてプロジェクトの設定を見ていると、「セーフモードで開く」というのを見つけました。これで解決できました！ありがとうございました！
>
> 参考 http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/quick_start/cloud_ide/starting_project

現時点で上記URLに説明が見当たらなかったので補足しておくと、ダッシュボードでプロジェクトの右下にカーソルを乗せると出てくる歯車アイコンをクリックすると、当該メニューが現れます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

Cookieを初期化して強制ログアウトさせて、アプリの選択画面を出すのはどうでしょうか？

その後ダウンロードしてコードを書き直して、再度アップロードしたらどうでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
結論から言いますと、解決しました！

ただし、教えていただいた方法と別ですので共有の意味もこめて。

ソースをダウンロードしようと思ったのですが、その方法がわからず、ダッシュボードにてプロジェクトの設定を見ていると、
セーフモードで開く
というのを見つけました。これで解決できました！ありがとうございました！
参考
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/quick_start/cloud_ide/starting_project/

Comment: @hogehoge 自己解決した場合は、ご自分で回答を書いて承認してください。そうしてもらえると この質問が解決済みになるので SOでは推奨されてます。

Comment: Masahiroさんが自己解決したというわけではないでしょうから、編集をロールバックしました。また自己解決したと書いてほしいわけではなく、回答をまとめること、また質問者の方であれば「承認」という操作が行えるので、それをしていただけるとありがたい、という話です。